# How to add Icons to CMFCPopupMenu?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I would like to use `CMFCPopupMenu` for PopUpMenu during Right Click. How can I add Icons to `CMFCPopupMenu`?

Here is the Sample code that I tried in Basic MFC Application

```
CMFCPopupMenu* TestCMFCPopMenu = new CMFCPopupMenu;
TestCMFCPopMenu->InsertItem(CMFCToolBarMenuButton(1, NULL, -1, L"Item 1"));
TestCMFCPopMenu->InsertSeparator();
TestCMFCPopMenu->InsertItem(CMFCToolBarMenuButton(2, NULL, -1, L"Item 2"));
TestCMFCPopMenu->Create(this, 1000, 400, NULL);
```

The Result image of above code is below

[image: cmfcpopupmenu example]

Comment: Have a look at the third parameter that you are passing to `CMFCToolBarMenuButton`. "iImage: Index of the image for the button; or -1 if this button does not have an icon"

Comment: In an effort to avoid duplication, a quick Google on this showed this tutorial: http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/archive/2013/submenu-images.htm I have not tried it out.